# How do I plot a stacked bar with ggplot?

Tags: r, statistics, ggplot2

I have been going through the examples provided on [this](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_bar.html) page, but for some reason unable to find the right way of doing this.

I have some data like this:

```
      Group Member Percentage
 [1,] "1"   "A"    "60"      
 [2,] "1"   "A"    "20"      
 [3,] "1"   "A"    "20"      
 [4,] "1"   "B"    "80"      
 [5,] "1"   "B"    "5"       
 [6,] "1"   "B"    "5"       
 [7,] "1"   "B"    "5"       
 [8,] "2"   "C"    "50"      
 [9,] "2"   "C"    "50"      
[10,] "2"   "D"    "25"      
[11,] "2"   "D"    "25"      
[12,] "2"   "D"    "25"      
[13,] "2"   "D"    "20"      
[14,] "2"   "D"    "5"
```

and can be created with the following commands:

```
a = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
b = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","D","D","D","D","D")
c = c(60,20,20,80,5,5,5,50,50,25,25,25,20,5)
dat = data.frame(Group=a, Member=b, Percentage=c)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=Member, y=Percentage)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", fill="white", colour="black")
```

The last line gives me the following plot:

[image]

What I am really looking for is to concatenate each of the bars in one group to one single bar and represent the percentages as fraction of the same bar (where each member from each group is plotted with one bar with each bar having the percentages as their colors). So I used the following:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=Member, y=Percentage)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="white")
```

and obtained this:

[image]

But now I can't get the colors properly. I want something exactly like the one give below but I am not able to understand how to do this. Any suggestions on how to do this?

[image]

Comment: http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/position_stack.html

Comment: @gsk3: Just managed to do it after some experimentation though I did not use `position="stack"`. I wonder what the difference is. What would have been good is to limit ggplot from using limited colors instead of using one for every new percentage it finds.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok finally got it! Hurray! Here's the complete code if someone else is interested:

```
a = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
b = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","D","D","D","D","D")
c = c(60,20,20,80,5,5,5,50,50,25,25,25,20,5)
dat = data.frame(Group=a, Member=b, Percentage=c)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=Member, y=Percentage, fill=Percentage)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="white")
```

[image]

and with what was suggested by @joran (Thanks a lot!) in the comments:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=Member, y=Percentage, fill=Percentage)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="white")
```

[image]

Comment: Well done! I was just about to post this...note that if you want a discrete color scale on Percentage, rather than a continuous one, just use `fill = factor(Percentage)`.

Comment: +1 Oh wonderful! I was looking for this version! I could do away with a better color scheme though. Need to explore more on this.

Comment: As a slightly unrelated question, would you happen to know how to change that `factor(Percentage)` text on the legend to the right to something else by any chance?

Comment: Sure, `+ labs(fill = "Fill label")`

Answer (score 5):

You're close. Try

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=Member, y=Percentage, fill = factor(Percentage))) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Which produces

[image]

Comment: +1 Thank you for this! Just updated my answer with @joran's comments. I guess a little more tweaking and these graphs will look awesome.