# Bash Stacked Column

Tags: bash, graph

this is the first time I have posted here.

I am trying to make a stacked column in BASH but I cannot seem to get anywhere. I just have three different columns of data I would like to stack over time. I was able to do it in excel, but not sure how to get it to work in BASH.

I did find a similar question in this site but for a different program.

[plot stacked bar plot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583432/plot-stacked-bar-plot-in-r)

But I would only need one of the charts and not two. So if anyone knows how to do a similar graph in BASH, please let me know. I'm new to programming, so sorry if it is a dumb question.

Thanks...

Comment: the basic bash tool is a shell command interpreter. The only output it can make is directly into files or directly onto the computer screen as simple text inside putty, xterm, Terminal, et.al. You can create files in bash, that you can load into Excel OR load into a graphics program like R or graphvis. You write programs to read the data and make basic histograms, but I think that is about it. Best to edit your post to show some simple input data (5-10 lines max) and your required output. Good luck.

Comment: Why must you do this in bash but not R?

Comment: I was able to get it to plot as 3 line graphs, I just want to stack them now. I'm not sure if I can post a picture on this site, but if I can then i could show you what it looks like. but for the data, I can show you it: 0 153 44 20; 1 151 45 16; 2 145 45 25; 3 157 45 13; 4 142 44 31; 5 157 44 12. so what i want the 2, 3 and 4 columns to be stacked with the same first column. the first column is just time on the x axis.

Comment: and i suppose i could do this in R, but I have never used it before and i'm not sure how to change from bash to R, and if i can even do that on the machine i'm using. sorry, once again i'm new to all this.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work, but I tried to put the image into a html. file:///Users/gavin/Desktop/station.png

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple to use java package called livegraph (http://www.live-graph.org/). You feed to it an input file, with a few metadata lines on top of the input file, and it graphs it for you, in real time too. I used it in Ubuntu and it worked like a charm.