# Make bins of each table row and draw stack bar figure in R

Tags: r

I am planning to make stack bar diagram like in this post
[plot stacked bar plot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583432/plot-stacked-bar-plot-in-r)

I have raw data in tabular format without any title (this each row contains seven values):

```
1.028 1.125 1.475 0.793 0.803 0.815 0.974
0.867 1.115 1.256 1.377 1.029 1.184 1.135
0.497 0.400 0.313 0.570 0.319 0.558 0.475
0.541 0.646 0.309 0.692 0.813 0.575 0.806
1.153 1.184 0.792 0.666 0.976 0.607 0.706
1.236 1.049 1.424 1.773 1.019 0.910 1.376
```

My plan is first to make bins in different interval of step size 1 for each row.

```
0-1  1-2  2-3
4    3    0
1    6    0
...
```

second to make stack bar of intervals of each row in x-axis.

I have done a lot of googling. I am stopped here....

```
> mytable = read.table("./temp.out")
> m <-apply(mytable, 1, cut, seq(0, 3, 1))
> m
[,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]    [,5]    [,6]    [,7]
[1,] "(1,2]" "(0,1]" "(0,1]" "(0,1]" "(0,1]" "(1,2]" "(1,2]"

[2,] "(1,2]" "(1,2]" "(0,1]" "(0,1]" "(0,1]" "(1,2]" "(1,2]"

[3,] "(1,2]" "(1,2]" "(0,1]" "(0,1]" "(0,1]" "(0,1]" "(1,2]"

[4,] "(0,1]" "(1,2]" "(0,1]" "(0,1]" "(0,1]" "(0,1]" "(1,2]"

[5,] "(0,1]" "(1,2]" "(0,1]" "(0,1]" "(0,1]" "(0,1]" "(1,2]"

[6,] "(0,1]" "(1,2]" "(0,1]" "(0,1]" "(0,1]" "(0,1]" "(0,1]"

[7,] "(0,1]" "(1,2]" "(0,1]" "(0,1]" "(0,1]" "(0,1]" "(1,2]"
```

After, I am unable to convert this in frequency table as

```
0-1  1-2  2-3
4    3    0
1    6    0
...
```

Could you suggest me how frequency table can be made?
After getting frequency table, those data can be plotted in stack bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the info you want with an anonymous function like so :

```
m <- t(apply(mytable, 1, function(x) table(cut(x,seq(0, 3, 1)))))

> m
     (0,1] (1,2] (2,3]
[1,]     4     3     0
[2,]     1     6     0
[3,]     7     0     0
[4,]     7     0     0
[5,]     5     2     0
[6,]     1     6     0
```

If you leave the data in the transposed format without the `t` like so...

```
m <- apply(mytable, 1, function(x) table(cut(x,seq(0, 3, 1))))
```

...you can just barplot that as it is:

```
barplot(m)
```

Comment: @Exchhattu - no problems - if that is the case, please hit the tick mark next to this answer so future viewers of this question know it was the accepted answer.

Comment: can you help to put also legend?

Comment: @Exchhattu - take a read of `?legend` in R itself. There is a nice clear example of adding legends here as well: http://learningrbasic.blogspot.com.au/2009/07/adding-legend-to-plot.html