# How can I create plots with vertical bars for 2 or more data columns (similar to Clustered Columns in Excel) in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset for TV watching on Weekdays and Weekend for 7 students (named "TVwatch") as follows:

TV watching in hours:

```
Names   Wkdays Wkend        
Dawn     5.0    4.5
Steve    9.8    2.0
Lena     3.5    5.5
Patty    9.6    4.3
Ania     8.3    3.2
Beth     9.3    2.5
Roby     2.5    7.4
```

How can I create a comparison plot where vertical bars will show the hours of TVwatching on wkdays and wkends(on Y-axis) for each students (on X-axis) in R (similar to Clustered columns in Excel)?

Thanks,

Comment: It's not clear what your after exactly. Do you want to make a staked bar plot ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583432/plot-stacked-bar-plot-in-r

Comment: What all have you tried?  When asking questions here please show that you have done some research on your own before you arrived here and asked for code.  Using `melt` from the `reshape2` package and the `ggplot2` package this is very straight forward and has been asked and answered many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
library(lattice)
barchart(Wkdays + Wkend~Names,data=dat,auto.key=TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Lattice is a perfectly good way to go (+1 to @agstudy).  If you want a base R approach, you could try this:

```
d = read.table(text="Names   Wkdays Wkend        
Dawn     5.0    4.5
Steve    9.8    2.0
Lena     3.5    5.5
Patty    9.6    4.3
Ania     8.3    3.2
Beth     9.3    2.5
Roby     2.5    7.4", header=T)

d = t(as.matrix(d[,2:3]))
d = as.table(d)
colnames(d) = c("Dawn", "Steve", "Lena", "Patty", "Ania", "Beth", "Roby")

windows()
  barplot(d, beside=T)
```

[image]

The key function is [?barplot](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/graphics/html/barplot.html), and the key argument is `beside=TRUE`.  You can learn more about barplots in R at the [Quick-R website](http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/bar.html).